# Cell editing and "Substance" L&F in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, look-and-feel

This is a duet of questions which I think are better
answered together.

1) How do I make my entire JTable uneditable? (Is there any other way except putting
it into a loop and using the isCellEditable method?)

2)Now the more tricky one; I am using a DefaultTableCellRenderer() which I have overriden in order to change a couple of stuff like fonts etc. The problem is that I am also using the substance L&F in my app and if I use:
  `table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, renderer);`
 then I get my new fonts but the L&F will go away for the entire JTable.

Frankly I am after the shaded coloring effect on every other row of the substance skin and I don't want to lose it but at the same I would also like to use my "extended renderer"...

Any ideas?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

For 1), just have your TableModel always return false from the [isCellEditable()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#isCellEditable%28int,int%29) method.  If you are just using a plain instance of DefaultTableModel, extend it in order to override this method.

For 2), you might be able to change the JTable fonts in the LookAndFeel UIDefaults.  The UIDefaults class contains many font, color, spacing, and other settings for the look and feel.

Comment: Could you please be a little more specific..? (for both of them)

Comment: @Konos5, I added more detail including a link to the API isCellEditable method.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! For the 1) I am using a plain Instance of isCellEditable and wouldn't like to extend the entire class just to change a return from true to false...I am surprised that there is not a single method dealing with such a simple issue...2)Would you mind giving me precise instructions on how to use it??(I know I ask spoonfeeding but I am pretty confused right now...)

Comment: @Konos5: [`UIManager Defaults`](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/) is an excellent resource on this topic.

Comment: I read the article but still not sure how to use UIManager Defaults. The thing is that if I extend the customTableCellRenderer and consequently set the fonts and the alignment I want, I'll lose the substance look and feel and the other way around! Is there any way to force the L&F into a component? Tables are giving me a very rough time..!

Comment: Per-Erik Svensson's answer for 2) is also potentially valid depending on what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

Bit late but

1) I'm assuming you're using a DefaultTableModel?

```
JTable table = null;
Vector dataVector = null;
Vector columnNames = null;
table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(dataVector, columnNames) {
    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Generally, it's not a big issue extending on single methods in Java and I can't say I understand why you don't want to do it. Moreover, in general, a component shouldn't be responsible for deciding editability. What would it mean to setEditable(true) on a JTable that has a table model that fetches data from, say, an RSS-feed? You can't edit the feed and only the model knows it. An in-memory document is always editable though, so it works for JTextComponent and its sub-classes (JTextArea, JTextPane, JEditorPane, JTextField).

2) Instead of extending DefaultTableCellRenderer, extend SubstanceDefaultTableCellRenderer. That should do the trick. That is, Substance want you to return a sub-class of SubstanceDefaultTableCellRenderer from the getTableCellRendererComponent. This should be no problem if you only change font and font color. Just extend SubstanceDefaultTableCellRenderer and override getTableCellRendererComponent to look something like

```
class MyTableRenderer extends SubstanceDefaultTableCellRenderer {
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

        JLabel label = (JLabel)super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table,
            value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 14));
        return label;
    }
}
```

This is Substance-specific and I can't say I like it very much. Has caused a few headaches for me since I have a lot of custom renderers that I would very much like not to be dependent on Substance.